# ARCore – Object does not show in correct depth in Face Augmentation

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I tried to place an object on face. But does not understand how to set depth in object.

Like when I add 3d object like spects frames on face.

**It does not show in** [correct depth](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NBAu64LpRLgfJ7M7UU8DDh0iuIzwUhKB/view).

Comment: you need to use proper model. for eye glasses  you can find online assets. if you didint get proper then let me know i ll send sample code

Answer (score 3):

When you use [Augmented Faces](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/ios/augmented-faces) feature, it's worth to note that if any face is detected, ARCore at first puts a Face Anchor (which must be located behind a nose or, more precise to say, inside a skull), and secondly ARCore puts a canonical mask – its pivot point resides on the same place as anchor does.

Hence, if you wanna place your glasses at the appropriate depth – set a pivot point of your 3D object the same way it was set on a canonical mask. In other words – marry these pivot points.

Comment: Thanks for your guideline. Can you tell me how can i set pivot point to 3d object. Does it works is done by android code or it is a designer task

Comment: The simplest way to set it – to set it in 3D authoring app. In Autodesk Maya, for instance, you can do it this way: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Basics/files/GUID-150B390E-840B-4FE3-B8E9-8DEBCE7CEC97-htm.html

Comment: Would it work the same way by changing the origin in blender?
I'm trying to fit the origin ahead of the glases so it could fit the NOSE_TIP but it doesn´t fit

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is getting the canonical face mesh from here

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/assets/canonical_face_mesh.fbx

And as described very nicely here on this blog post by Kristina Simakova:
https://creativetech.blog/home/try-on-glasses-arcore-augmented-faces

In blender you can set whatever model you want at any place on that face mesh,
while also maintaining scale, which is very important.
Also very important is this part:

> Following the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-faces/create-assets#customizing_the_canonical_face_mesh) from ARCore documentation, add the glass
> model under “asset“ object. Check out this short tutorial to learn
> about parenting in Blender.